# SonarQube icons are not showing correctly

Tags: sonarqube

Lately our SonarQube PR analyses have been with broken images, as it seems that the requests to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-github/master/images/severity-major.png` generate `404: Not Found`.

And our PRs look like this:[image]

I could not open up ticket as it seems SonarQube community requires that the issues are to be discussed in StackOverflow. Anyone else having similar issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL to static images are hardcoded to the old GitHub source repository (SonarCommunity/sonar-github). GitHub used to provide a redirection, but it is no more working.

There's a ticket to fix this ([SONARGITUB-32](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGITUB-32)) and we're going to make a release soon.